# I wanna add Images, video, audio and files in listview; So my listview will looks like chat conversation in android; How could i make it?

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, getview

I wanna add Images, video, audio and files in listview; i have used getview too. So my listview will looks like chat conversation in android;
I am adding images, video, audio and file from SD Card; and all things getting add in list but when i add image then video getting disappear similarly when i add video all added images getting disappear; but i wanna show both in a list
How could i make it?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

switch(sItem){
            case "Image":
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = li.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null);
                    viewHolder1 = new CompleteListViewHolderImage(v);
                    v.setTag(viewHolder1);
                } else {
                    viewHolder1 = (CompleteListViewHolderImage) v.getTag();
                }
                Log.d("path","Path: + : "+Uri.parse(list.get(position)));
                viewHolder1.imageView1.setImageURI(Uri.parse(list.get(position)));
                break;
            case "Video":
                if(v == null){
                    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = li.inflate(R.layout.video_layout, null);
                    viewHolder2 = new CompleteListViewHolderVideo(v);
                    v.setTag(viewHolder2);
                }else {
                    viewHolder2 = (CompleteListViewHolderVideo) v.getTag();
                }
                Bitmap bmThumbnail;
                bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(list.get(position), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                viewHolder2.videoView1.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
                break;
        }
        return v;
}

class CompleteListViewHolderImage{
        public ImageView imageView1;
        public CompleteListViewHolderImage(View base) {
            imageView1 = (ImageView) base.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        }
    }
    class CompleteListViewHolderVideo{
        public ImageView videoView1;
        public CompleteListViewHolderVideo(View base) {
            videoView1 = (ImageView) base.findViewById(R.id.vview);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to determine `sItem` individually for each call to `getView()`.

Comment: Ok thanx @Mike M.
I will try n let you know..